# AMDGPU-Pro on Juno to improve performance and compability

Tags: graphic-drivers, amd

Is there a way to install the amdgpu-pro drivers for elementary juno to improve gaming performance? I'm new to linux and I'm trying to get a picture here: On how to improve the gaming performance and maybe even fix game issues with newer drivers. I know that the standard drivers support my 2x RX-480 but I don't know how good they do this.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the latest MESA drivers, you could add the official repositories:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

They work very well in my case, even in games.

BUT if you want to install the proprietary drivers, you must make some modifications in the system.

First go ahead and download the driver from the official website (AMD).

You will need to edit the system file 
`/etc/os-release`

> on line 3 of ID=elementary to ID=ubuntu and on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "5.0" to VERSION_ID = "18.04"

if you are using Eos Juno (open "files" with administrator privileges for to be able to make the change).

Then CD with a terminal to the location of the driver and type:

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

(this installs the Base kernel, Accelerated graphics, Multimedia table, Pro OpenGL, Pro Vulkan, Pro OpenCL).

After installing everything correctly edit the system file **/etc/os-release** again, on line 3 of ID=ubuntu to ID=elementary and on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "18.04" to VERSION_ID = "5.0" to leave that file as it was before.

[install AMD GPU driver](https://youtu.be/_zDLT9wQHmU)

Works pretty good for me, but I prefer to stay with the open MESA drivers because native linux games on steam recommends MESA drivers with vulkan support. For mesa support on open drivers:

`sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers`

Comment: I tried the the amdgpu pro like this but It couldn't install amdgpu-pro core last time thats why it failed. And my whole system broke. Did it work for you? Because it said it is not for Ubuntu 16.04 thats why it can't install the amdgpu-pro core.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. the YouTube video shows what I did on my personal computer. Now I do not use the proprietary drivers, but I do use proprietary drivers for quite some time. use AMDGPU-Pro on loki and juno and they worked well

Comment: so you tried the mesa drivers and amdgpu? But recomment prop. driver with the newest mesa build?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you're asking me. What I recommend is to use the latest MESA drivers.

Comment: I wonder if you'd recommend not having this `deb [trusted=yes] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./` set or not? Does that prevent me updating or hard-code my version? Just noticed I should run `ppa-purge` prior will do. I'm on Zorin so I am about to kludge my os to ubuntu and back to zorin later. Spicy.