# Can't get AMD video card working

Tags: amd

Relatively new to Linux. Lenovo T495 - AMD Ryzen™ 7 PRO 3700U - AMD Vega 10 graphics. Can't get video card working properly and can't install AMD pro drivers because of a 'failed for running kernel' warning.

Started shortly after the fresh install I went through the black screen at login and had to add 'nomodeset' in grub to get in. I then, based off [another post here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/amdgpu-pro-on-juno-to-improve-performance-and-compability), I installed the mesa and vulkan drivers with this code:

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

That solved the black screen problem, as I was able to remove 'nomodeset' and have a normal boot screen without issue. But I have all sorts of video issues. Playback in 'Library' is slow/glitchy on a 1080p video. And even when I close the video the audio keeps playing and I have to kill the process in Monitor. Playback of videos in VLC is smoother but the screen flashes black when I adjust volume or brightness with the F keys.

I then followed that post's advice for how to install the AMD Pro drivers, but at the end it says:

```
WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel
```

So I uninstalled the amd pro drivers (otherwise I can't login cause it just keeps looping back to the login screen), and I followed instructions and installed ukuu and changed the kernel from 5.3.0 to 5.4.13 and then the latest kernel (I think it was 5.5 something), each time trying to install amd pro drivers and each time got the same 'failed for running kernel warning'.

I also tried the suggestion from somewhere to also manually install with this code

```
sudo apt install amdgpu-dkms libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm2-amdgpu
```

Same result.

I don't know what to do anymore. When I decided to quit Apple I expected some difficulties, but when I test drove things with an NVIDIA Macbook I could install the proprietary drivers in the AppCenter. With AMD it feels like we're just completely left to our own devices. Am I missing something? I'm 2 days into working on this. There has to be a way, but I'm not finding anything out there...

Really appreciate any help.

Comment: have you tried using the AMD pro drivers following the instructions at https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/AMDGPU-INSTALLATION? If you look about halfway down the page there's instructions for Vega 10 and above './amdgpu-pro-install -y --opencl=rocm
'

Comment: what kernel are you running? `$ uname -a`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to start again with a fresh install of elementary. Just install, update your system and install any driver that may appear on AppCenter. You can also execute `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to be sure you are not missing any driver!

You may need to use the `nomodeset` parameter on the first boot to avoid that black screen.

After that, reboot your computer and check if it works fine. To solve screen flickering issues I think it will be enough to just tweak the driver settings, there's no need to install development versions for that matter.

Comment: Hey Maccer, thanks for the the advice. I did as you said and did a fresh install. nomodeset was needed from grub the first time rebotting (after having already logged in once), but as you said wasn't needed after.

But how do I tweak the driver settings? Playback on a 1080p mp4 is still pretty bad. Still flashes when I adjust volume etc with F keys, still choppy. But I don't know how to tweak the driver settings to fix this...?

Comment: Try this from terminal: `export VDPAU_DRIVER_PATH=/opt/amdgpu/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau  export VDPAU_DRIVER=radeonsi vlc`. Change VLC with your media player and play a video. Is it still choppy?

Comment: May also want to install the propietary driver if for some reason it wasn't installed on previous steps `sudo apt install amdgpu-pro rocm-amdgpu-pro`

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues, reinstalled it on AMD Ryzen 7 4700U APU. Still no second monitor, still apparently no driver that works already installed. Guess I will tinker and go break it entirely once again because nobody can simply say "no, AMD APUs are not supported" so that it is clear that I won't get it working until the drivers I try out, support it.

If there is an open source driver coming with eOS, it certainly does not work for AMD APUs.