# Can't install AMD drivers on ElementaryOS Hera - Unsupported DEB-based OS

Tags: release-hera, drivers, amd

I am trying to install AMD drivers for my RX 480 8GB GPU and I'm following [this article from AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-635) to install it.

When I get to the point of running this command

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

It throws an error saying: `Unsupported DEB-based OS: /etc/os-release ID 'elementary'`

I looked it up on the internet and I found one article about it. It was [this one](https://community.amd.com/thread/220723). In the answer, it says to find "ubuntu" string inside the code of the `amdgpu-pro-install` and replace it with `debian`. But I can't find the `ubuntu` string inside of that file, maybe the code changed since the question was asked.

What I see in that file is

```
function os_release() {
        if [[ -r  /etc/os-release ]]; then
                . /etc/os-release

                case "$ID" in
                ubuntu|linuxmint|debian)
                        :
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo "Unsupported DEB-based OS: `
                                `/etc/os-release ID '$ID'" | stderr
                        exit 1
                        ;;
                esac
        else
                echo "Unsupported OS" | stderr
                exit 1
        fi
}
```

There is `ubuntu` in the `case` but I don't think that's it.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you please tell where is the file exactly present in which we have to change the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will must make some modifications in the system, look this link:

[AMDGPU-Pro on Juno to improve performance and compability](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/amdgpu-pro-on-juno-to-improve-performance-and-compability/19023#19023)

Comment: Does it matter if this answer is for Juno version? I am using Hera.

Comment: sure! just change this: on line 3 of ID=elementary to ID=ubuntu and on line 6 of VERSION_ID = "5.1" to VERSION_ID = "18.04"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code correctly, it checks the name of the release (in your case `elementary`) and tries to match it to `ubuntu|linuxmint|debian` (`|` means or). If release is different from any of this options, it prints `Unsupported DEB-based OS:`.

Based on this, I would try to replace `debian` with `elementary` and see what happens.

Comment: Exactly. You are absolutely right. | means or so just add after debian | elementary

Comment: but there is a problem, many files have that check, is more "easy" if u do the system modification ;)

Answer (score 0):

`ubuntu|linuxmint|debian|zorin|kubuntu|elementary)`

Could work, but since this mod is maybe needed in other files, faking your os ID may work better:

```
echo SETUP KLUDGE OF OS RELEASE to ubuntu
sudo mv /etc/os-release /etc/os-release-backup
sudo cat /etc/os-release-backup | sudo grep -v ^ID= > /etc/os-release-ubuntu
sudo echo "ID=ubuntu" >> /etc/os-release-ubuntu
sudo mv /etc/os-release-ubuntu /etc/os-release
cat /etc/os-release
```

then `./amdgpu-pro-install -y` and to restore the backup and put back to what you had:

```
echo REMOVE KLUDGE OF OS RELEASE restore backup
sudo mv /etc/os-release        /etc/os-release-ubuntu
sudo mv /etc/os-release-backup /etc/os-release
cat /etc/os-release
```

Careful with the > it likes to wipe files.
Use >> to add / append to them. Not sure if the order matters.