# Hera 5.1 Stable installer boots to corrupted graphics on AMD 550RX 4GB

Tags: system-installation, release-hera, graphic-drivers, graphics, amd

While attempting to boot the `elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200814.iso` installer with an AMD Radeon 550RX with 4GB RAM I'm seeing corrupted graphics and not sure how to proceed:
[image]

For what it's worth, I ran through the installation with another older significantly slower GPU and then updated the system following the install. I then put the 550RX back in and was met with very similar graphical corruption.

### Update 1 - still no joy:

Attempted to follow [these instructions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/19023) wherein I then installed [the drivers from AMD for 18.04.5 HWE](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-550).

`lsmod` shows:

```
$ lsmod | grep amd
amdgpu               4530176  0
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                   102400  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        188416  1 amdgpu
drm                   491520  4 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
```

Details of the system via `inxi` are:

```
$ ./inxi --admin --verbosity=7 --filter --no-host --width -G --display

System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-77-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 
  parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-77-generic 
  root=UUID=a816ea97-c8b4-4021-8956-87e8b030ad78 ro text splash amdgpu.dc=0 
  vt.handoff=1 
  Desktop: Pantheon info: wingpanel, plank vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.26.0 
  Distro: elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop System: Dell product: Inspiron 530s v: N/A serial: <filter> 
  Chassis: type: 3 serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0RY007 v: ��� serial: <filter> BIOS: Dell v: 1.0.7 
  date: 11/03/2007 
Battery:
  Message: No system battery data found. Is one present? 
Memory:
  RAM: total: 2.68 GiB used: 1.15 GiB (43.0%) 
  RAM Report: permissions: Unable to run dmidecode. Root privileges required. 
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core model: Intel Pentium Dual E2140 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Core Merom family: 6 model-id: F (15) stepping: D (13) microcode: A4 
  cache: L2: 1024 KiB bogomips: 6383 
  Speed: 1596 MHz min/max: 1200/1600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1596 2: 1596 
  Flags: acpi aperfmperf apic arch_perfmon bts clflush cmov constant_tsc cpuid 
  cx16 cx8 de ds_cpl dtes64 dtherm dts est fpu fxsr ht lahf_lm lm mca mce mmx 
  monitor msr mtrr nopl nx pae pat pbe pdcm pebs pge pni pse pse36 pti 
  rep_good sep sse sse2 ssse3 syscall tm tm2 tsc vme xtpr 
  Vulnerabilities: Type: itlb_multihit status: KVM: Vulnerable 
  Type: l1tf mitigation: PTE Inversion 
  Type: mds 
  status: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT disabled 
  Type: meltdown mitigation: PTI 
  Type: spec_store_bypass status: Vulnerable 
  Type: spectre_v1 
  mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization 
  Type: spectre_v2 
  mitigation: Full generic retpoline, STIBP: disabled, RSB filling 
  Type: srbds status: Not affected 
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected 
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Lexa PRO [Radeon RX 550/550X] driver: N/A alternate: amdgpu 
  bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:699f class-ID: 0300 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: loaded: ati,vesa 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon display-ID: :0 screens: 1 
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1280x1024 s-dpi: 95 s-size: 342x271mm (13.5x10.7") 
  s-diag: 436mm (17.2") 
  Monitor-1: default res: 1280x1024 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.1.0-devel 
  compat-v: 3.1 direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio vendor: Dell Inspiron 530 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 chip-ID: 8086:293e 
  class-ID: 0403 
  Device-2: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 01:00.1 
  chip-ID: 1002:aae0 class-ID: 0403 
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.4.0-77-generic running: yes 
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 11.1 running: yes 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82562V-2 10/100 Network vendor: Dell Inspiron 530 
  driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k port: ff00 bus-ID: 00:19.0 chip-ID: 8086:10c0 
  class-ID: 0200 
  IF: enp0s25 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
  IP v4: <filter> type: dynamic noprefixroute scope: global 
  broadcast: <filter> 
  IP v6: <filter> type: noprefixroute scope: link 
  WAN IP: <filter> 
Bluetooth:
  Message: No bluetooth data found. 
Logical:
  Message: No logical block device data found. 
RAID:
  Hardware-1: Intel SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 port: f400 
  bus-ID: 00:1f.2 chip-ID: 8086.2822 rev: 02 class-ID: 0104 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 10.51 GiB (0.9%) 
  SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends 
  ID-1: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 vendor: Crucial model: CT250MX500SSD1 
  size: 232.89 GiB block-size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s 
  rotation: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 023 temp: 44 C scheme: MBR 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM014-1EJ164 
  size: 931.51 GiB block-size: physical: 4096 B logical: 512 B speed: 3.0 Gb/s 
  rotation: 5400 rpm serial: <filter> rev: SM11 temp: 41 C scheme: MBR 
  Optical-1: /dev/sr0 vendor: TSSTcorp model: DVD+-RW TS-H653B rev: D300 
  dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw 
  Features: speed: 48 multisession: yes audio: yes dvd: yes 
  rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r state: running 
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 232.88 GiB size: 228.23 GiB (98.00%) 
  used: 10.51 GiB (4.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1 label: N/A 
  uuid: a816ea97-c8b4-4021-8956-87e8b030ad78 
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default) 
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 
  file: /swapfile 
Unmounted:
  ID-1: /dev/sdb1 maj-min: 8:17 size: 118.85 GiB fs: ext4 label: N/A 
  uuid: 22605079-ad0a-4a0a-9138-a6b9a1bb3c06 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb2 maj-min: 8:18 size: 1 KiB fs: <superuser required> 
  label: N/A uuid: N/A 
  ID-3: /dev/sdb5 maj-min: 8:21 size: 2 GiB fs: swap label: N/A 
  uuid: ea8bf147-e28c-4131-9401-f45d7846dfb6 
  ID-4: /dev/sdb6 maj-min: 8:22 size: 810.67 GiB fs: ext4 label: N/A 
  uuid: 63004dab-0841-4dd1-ac21-03f036f7d761 
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 6 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-2: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 6 rev: 2.0 
  speed: 480 Mb/s chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-3: 3-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0001 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-4: 4-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0001 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-5: 5-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0001 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-6: 5-1:2 info: Microsoft Internet Keyboard Pro ports: 3 rev: 1.1 
  speed: 12 Mb/s power: 64mA chip-ID: 045e:001c class-ID: 0900 
  Device-1: 5-1.1:3 info: Microsoft Natural Keyboard Pro type: Keyboard,HID 
  driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 1.5 Mb/s 
  power: 100mA chip-ID: 045e:001d class-ID: 0300 
  Device-2: 5-1.2:4 info: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse v2.0 type: Mouse 
  driver: hid-generic,usbhid interfaces: 1 rev: 1.1 speed: 1.5 Mb/s 
  power: 100mA chip-ID: 045e:00cb class-ID: 0301 
  Hub-7: 6-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0001 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-8: 7-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0001 class-ID: 0900 
  Hub-9: 8-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s 
  chip-ID: 1d6b:0001 class-ID: 0900 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0 C mobo: N/A 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 164 Uptime: 37m wakeups: 0 Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 
  tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 7.5.0 alt: 7 Packages: apt: 1788 lib: 890 
  flatpak: 0 Shell: Bash v: 4.4.20 running-in: tty pts/0 (vt 7) inxi: 3.3.04
```

Answer (score 1):

### SOLVED:

One thing I noticed while going through this old system was that it only had 2GB of RAM. I happened to have some memory laying around that worked for this system and after upgrading it to only 4GB of RAM and booting it up the 550RX fired right up.

It appears that this GPU needs more than 2GB of system memory to function.